# Dynamic data chart in x and y axis

Tags: excel, charts, dynamic-data, vba

I'm developing raport generator with fixed data range.
My row and column number vary from 'A34' to 'V64'. Each active column have same amount of rows. Active columns are placed next to each other, from left hand side to the right.

Things I've tried:

- Chart from table but it does not look good as chart is full-sized no matter of data amount.
- Macro record
- VBA but I'm stuck after dynamic range on X-axis

Unfortunatelly I cannot post images yet but below is example data, blue represents possible data range
http://oi63.tinypic.com/21zp5d [dot] jpg

Thanks and have good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is finding data range and exporting that into chart, using VBA.
Start at C34
-Go to the right till you find first empty cell
-Go to the bottom till you find first empty cell
Now you can work on x,y coordinates and create your data range.

But I'm still open to new ideas